# How to store avro and its schema in a protobuf and serialize/deserialize?

Tags: java, protocol-buffers, avro

I have an `avro` schema and `avro` that I want to shove into a protobuf.

Specifically, I have two variables:

```
1 - Schema myschema; (this is the avro schema in the org.apache.avro)
2- Map<Long, Schema> myschemamap  (this is a map containing a long of schema objects)
```

The protobuf doesn't support "schema" and "map", but it looks like it supports "bytes". What is the simplest way I can shove these two different variables into two different fields in protobuf and "deserilize" them back to the original Schema and Map objects above?

Answer (score 0):

A very simple solution (though certainly not the fastest or most space efficient) is to use the [JSON representation of the Schema](http://avro.apache.org/docs/1.7.7/api/java/org/apache/avro/Schema.html#toString()) and store it in a string field of a protobuf. You are correct that there are no maps in protobufs, but you can iterate over the map and save each entry. Then deserialize by iterating over each entry of the repeated field and rebuilding the Map. Here's a protobuf definition you could use:

```
message SchemaHolder {
  optional string schema = 1;
  repeated MapEntry schema_map = 2;
}

message MapEntry {
  optional int64 key = 1;
  optional string value = 2;
}
```